# HTML5 FlexBox to stretch Vertically not Horizontal

Tags: html, flexbox

The flex boxes I have are stretching horizontally and not vertically.I am looking at the code and the work Horizontal is not even in there so I am unsure how it's even doing that.

### I asked the professor about it and she gave me a hint

For part 2, the boxes need to expand vertically when hovering. So change the orientation to "vertical" and do adjustments for sizes of height in .flexbox ,  .flexbox > div, .flexbox > div:hover.  The book example adjusts width. 
If there is overflow, use overflow :hidden in flexbox div. so text will not overflow when the mouse is not hovering.

Hope the above hints will help.

Here is a link to the actual page. Can someone point out what word I need to change?

http://wmelliott.x10host.com/Fig5_13_Redo/Fig5_13_Redo.html

[My Work that's moving horizontal rather than vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lUP9.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce the issue **in the question itself**, preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There is a property `flex-direction`. As i can see in the image you should use `flex-direction:column` hope that helps.Note that this property would be used in the parent flex container.